# Testnet chaindata folder size huge (26.9 GBs)

Tags: testnets, network

How come my testnet chaindata folder is so big? 
I'm running Ethereum Wallet 0.8.7. Deploying little test smart contracts.
Actual chaindata size is 9.4 GBs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are you're looking at the *public* testnet, Morden. It's a full blockchain, so gigabytes of data isn't surprising--it's not just you, it's everyone else's little smart contracts!

If you need a *private* testnet, you'll have to manually set one up--but it is relatively simple to do so. [Browser Solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/) will create one for you in your browser. [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) also creates one instantly, but I don't know how well it meshes with Ethereum Wallet. If all else fails, you can set up a real, honest-to-goodness private blockchain on geth with the instructions [here](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/network/test-networks.html#setting-up-a-local-private-testnet), then Ethereum Wallet will definitely connect.

Comment: Yes, I've used testrpc, but want to use it with my wallet, so I will check out setting up my own testnet. Thanks!

Am I understanding your explanation correctly in extrapolating that the Morden Testnet has more contracts written to it than the public chain?

Comment: I doubt it. While everyone who uses Morden contributes to its size, there's even more users of the mainnet. My (mainnet) chaindata is 16 gigabytes, for example.

Comment: My Morden testnet chaindata (/Libary/Ethereum/testnet/chaindata) is 32GB on Nov 23 2016. Is something going wrong?

Comment: I don't know, but Morden itself recently broke (accidental geth/parity consensus failure). Instructions for using Ropsten (the new testnet) can be found [here](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/11/20/from-morden-to-ropsten/).